# gpg-agent: how to limit the passphrase cache retention time

Tags: gnupg, passphrase, enigmail

I'm using Thunderbird/Enigmail, and the plugin tells me that the process in charge of the passphrase cache is `gpg-agent`. The retention time of the passphrase is too long for me (possibly, the entire session). I would like to make it shorter, but so far I have failed to do so.

`gpg-agent` seems to be run without a `default-cache-ttl` argument (according to `ps`), so according to the manual it should use the default value, 600 seconds. It's obviously not the case. It should also use the default value for `max_cache_ttl` (2 hours), but it's not the case either.

I tried to create a `gpg-agent.conf` file in my `~/.gnupg` with a custom value for `default-cache-ttl`, but it seems to have no effect (I have restarted my session in order to restart `gpg-agent`).

Either I'm trying to tweak the wrong process, or it doesn't behave according to its specifications, or there is something I don't understand.
How can I efficiently shorten this passphrase retention time?

Answer (score 2):

Let me begin by saying I had the exact same issue...

I found and post a [solution for configuring GPG passphrase cache retention time on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/381221/194774) on another question.

There is however a minor issue with the second method (disabling the GPG component of the GnomeKeyring) and Thunderbird/Enigmail: when the cache is cleared, you may get a message saying the password is wrong before any actual prompt for it; just click OK (to retry) and you will get the prompt.