# How can I force gpg to use gpg-agent over seahorse (gnome-keyring-daemon) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, gnupg, seahorse

I want to use gpg-agent (and its gpg.conf and gpg-agent.conf files) when I invoke gpg (from Enigmail or otherwise) but Ubuntu 12.04 uses seahorse as the default 'agent.' While seahorse may or may not read these conf files, how can I force gpg to bypass Ubuntu's setup and use gpg-agent?

This is what I see when I ask the terminal to return `$GNU_AGENT_INFO`:

```
user@user:~$ echo $GNU_AGENT_INFO  
/tmp/keyring-xxxxxx/gpg:0:1
```

Following the [gpg man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/gpg.1.html), I have tried adding the following lines to my gpg.conf file without desired result:

```
--gpg-agent-info=/usr/bin/gpg-agent  
--gpg-agent-info=/usr/bin/gpg-agent:0:1
```

Thanks.

PS: In addition, does seahorse use equivalent files of the same path and name (`gpg.conf`, `gpg-agent.conf`)? If not, what are the paths and names I could use to reach equivalent result?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349238/how-can-i-clear-my-cached-gpg-password):

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop.disabled
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 13.04.  It disables the gpg part of gnome keyring.