# `pass` timeout cached master password

Tags: password, gnupg

I use a password manager called `pass`. It asks for the master password upon its first invocation. It appears to cache the master password as to avoid rewriting it. For security reasons, I would like to set a timeout.

I have looked through the pass script in `/usr/bin/pass`. I have not become wiser from that. My suspicion is that `gpg-agent` has something to do with it. I tried the answers/comments from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349238/how-can-i-clear-my-cached-gpg-password). They did not help.

**Question**: How do I clear the master password cache?
If it has a built-in timeout, that would be nice. Otherwise it will just be a simple `cronjob`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using gpg-agent all passwords (including the master password) are stored/saved in `~/.password-store`.

From the "pass" [website](http://www.passwordstore.org/):

> There will be a nice password input dialog using the standard `gpg-agent` (**which can be configured to stay authenticated for several minutes**), since all passwords are encrypted.

gpg-agent [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent):

```
--default-cache-ttl n  Set the time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.       
The default is 600 seconds. 

--default-cache-ttl-ssh n Set the time a cache entry used for SSH keys 
is valid to n seconds. 
The default is 1800 seconds. 

--max-cache-ttl n  Set the maximum time a cache entry is valid to n seconds. 

After this time a cache entry will be expired even if it has been accessed recently. 
The default is 2 hours (7200 seconds). 

--max-cache-ttl-ssh n Set the maximum time a cache entry used for SSH keys is valid 
to n seconds. After this time a cache entry will be expired even if 
it has been accessed recently. 
The default is 2 hours (7200 seconds).
```

and ...

> gpg-agent.conf
>
> This is the standard configuration file read by gpg-agent on
>       startup. It may contain any valid long option; the leading
>       two dashes may not be entered and the option may not be abbreviated.
>       This file is also read after a SIGHUP however only a few
>       options will actually have an effect. This default name may be
>       changed on the command line (see: [option --options]).
>       You should backup this file.

This will only be read if you actually use gpg-agent. If it is "seahorse" (the default in Ubuntu) gpg-agent is ignored).

So you can put any of the 4 parameters in the configuration file with a time in seconds to keep password valid (that includes the master password since that is also stored in ). To release the passwords you can use `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent` ([see the manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dconnect_002dagent.html) for more options).

Comment: As I stated: the comments and answers from the linked question did not work. `$ echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
ERR 103 unknown command`

Comment: Using `gpg-agent --default-cache-ttl 10` has no effect. It does not request my master password after more than 10 seconds.

Comment: The reason why `$echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent` results in `ERR 103 unknown command` is that you have gnome-keyring acting as gpg-agent in your setup, and gnome-keyring doesn't recognize this command. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/884856 for an explanation on how to stop gnome-keyring from doing this. Specifically look at Pete Stephenson's comment from 2013-02-25.